# Sending emails using data across multiple tabs - two for loops?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Very much a beginner here - read through many similar-ish questions but can't figure out what I need. Many thanks in advance for any guidance!

I have a Google Sheet with 4 tabs. Tab 1 is the summary sheet and can be ignored. Tabs 2-4 have lists of email addresses and other info that I'd like to send along in the email. Below is my attempt at a script that loops through all the sheets except the Summary tab and sends a test email to the email addresses listed in the tabs. (Note, on Tabs 2-4, column A houses the names and column B houses the email addresses.)

The below script currently throws an '*Exception: Invalid email: Email (line 25, file "Code")*' error - leading me to believe I have some issue with the script finding my data in the sheets.

```
function sendEmailLoop() {

var sheets =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
var range = sheet.getDataRange();

if (sheet.getName() == "Summary") //Disregard tab named 'Summary' 
{      
}
else
{    
  var range = sheet.getDataRange(); //to set the range as array
  var values = range.getDisplayValues(); //to get the value in the array
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  //declare the spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var i;
  var logContent = '';

  for (i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) 
  {   
  var Name = values[i][0];       //[Name] cell A++
  var Email = values[i][1];      // [Email] cell B++

MailApp.sendEmail({
 to: Email,
 subject: Name + 'Test',
 message: 'This is a test message ' + Email + Name});

}; //end for loop - email tab data
};   // end 'else'
}); // end function(sheet)       
 } // end SendEmailLoop()
```

Note - I've also tried a couple similar looping functions to no avail:

1:

```
var allsheets = ss.getSheets(); 
for (var s in allsheets){
```

2:

```
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
```

Comment: Pl. check the email ID in the sheet. It may be malformed (having a comma, space, wrong symbol). The error is not about the code

Comment: @arulselvan Thanks for your reply. The email addresses are valid in the spreadsheets. Note that if I delete the variable for Email, I'll get the same error message for the 'Name' variable...which makes me think that the script isn't accessing the data in the tabs properly.

Comment: Can you put in a `Logger.log(Email);` after `var Email = values[i][1]` and see how the output is?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - here's the output from the log:                  
 `Exception: Invalid email: Email
    at [unknown function](Code:10:15)
    at sendEmails(Code:3:8)`

Comment: There should be a log before the error in the log. Try using `console.log(Email)` instead and check the logs in the stackdriver logs (`View > Stackdriver logging > Apps Script Dashboard`).

Comment: Hmmm, I get the same error message when viewed in Stackdriver Logs and using console.log(Email).

Comment: Can you please share a sanitised copy of you sheet?

Comment: Sure, thanks for looking into it. I cleaned [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19jCpHuAQkpSccHSrK_7cBxWCHHvOsYpn89q8APLRq5w/edit?usp=sharing) up and removed the email addresses in the Summary tab (which are pulled into the other tabs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The range you are retrieving from the sheet for the emails is incorrect.*

#### More Information:

In the Sheet you provided, the cells in which the emails are entered start from row 4, not row 1. See image below:

[image]

The logic you're using to loop through the emails is as follows:

```js
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getDisplayValues();
for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {   
  var Name = values[i][0];
  var Email = values[i][1];
}
```

However, as you've obtained the *whole* data range, and not just the data that you want, starting with the emails, the `values` array contains the headers too - in this case the object is as follows:

```
[[www.google.com], [], [EmpEmail], [EmpName1@blah.com], [EmpName2@blah.com]]
```

Thus, when you call `MailApp.sendEmail()` and specify `Email` as the first of this array, you get the `Exception: Invalid email: Email` error as you're trying to send an email to `www.google.com`.

#### Code fix:

Luckily, this is a simple fix. As you already have the data set in the array, you can change the boundaries of your loop to start at `3` instead of `0`:

```js
for (i = 3; i < lastRow; i++) {   
  var Name = values[i][0];
  var Email = values[i][1];
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Email,
    subject: Name + Title + 'Test',
    message: 'This is a test message for the training that can be found at ' + URL});
}
```

#### References:

- [Class `Sheet` | Apps Script - `getDataRange()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

Comment: Beautiful - thank you! The error was in plain sight. The script runs without visible error now, but no emails are actually sent... The Stackdriver logs contain a 'debug' line for each email address in the log. Could that point towards the issue?  [Screenshot of log here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jb_7QGceMIoUUUc3E3fJZlQ7HjUq-axb/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Got it - thank you very much for all your help. Very much appreciated!! The other post has been created and is linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347145/mailapp-sendemail-function-runs-without-errors-but-no-emails-are-sent)

Answer (score 0):

I slightly rewrote your code and it is working for me:

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheets =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var Name = values[i][0];
      var Email = values[i][1]; 
      MailApp.sendEmail({
 to: Email,
 subject: Name + ' Test',
 message: 'This is a test message ' + Email + Name});
    }
}
});
}
```

My sheet1 looks like this:

```
name1 email1@email.com
name2 email2@email.com
```

If you are still running into the same issue, the cell formatting in your sheet or the email format may be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for testing this out. I tried your code and still got the issue; I then hard-coded my email address into the script instead of using the Email variable, and then it went through. Two questions, though:  (1) The script still runs on just one sheet. My goal is to get it to loop through multiple sheets. (2) I have no idea how my cell formatting could be off. I have another proof of concept script working with the email service, and the formatting in that spreadsheet is the same as in this spreadsheet. Any guidance on either (1) or what I should be looking for re: format of (2)? Thank you!