# MailApp.sendEmail function runs without errors but no emails are sent

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below script runs without any visible error, but no emails are sent. Any ideas as to why?

```
function sendEmailLoop() {

  var sheets =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();

    if (sheet.getName() == "Summary") //Disregard tab named 'Summary' 
    {      
    }
    else {    
      var range = sheet.getDataRange(); //to set the range as array
      var values = range.getDisplayValues(); //to get the value in the array
      var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  //declare the spreadsheet
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var Title = values[0][0];         //[Title] cell A1
      var URL = values[0][1];           //[URL] cell B1
      var i;
      var logContent = '';

      for (i = 3; i < lastRow; i++) {   
        var Name = values[i][0];     //[Name] cell A++
        var Email = values[i][1];        // [Email] cell B++

        Logger.log('to: ' + Email);
        Logger.log('subject: ' + Name + Title + 'Test');
        Logger.log('message: ' + 'This is a test message for the training that can be found at ' + URL);
        /*
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: Email,
          subject: Name + Title + 'Test',
          message: 'This is a test message for the training that can be found at ' + URL});
        */
      }; //end for loop - email tab data
    };   // end 'else'
  }); // end function(sheet)       
} // end SendEmailLoop()
```

Here is the Stackdriver log of a successful execution (success meaning no errors, but still no emails are sent):

[image: Stackdriver log]

The structure of the spreadsheet associated with the script:

[image: spreadsheet associated with the script]

Note - an earlier version of this script didn't include the `sheets.forEach()` method call (ie, to loop through each tab of the spreadsheet) and the emails were sent fine.

Could the lack of emails being sent or received be related to the fact that I have many sheets and this function is looping through them?

Comment: Just note you are probably aware of - beware [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) as you do (M - 1) * (N - 3) sendouts per run (where M is # of sheets, N is # of rows) which can grow out of control pretty fast.

Comment: Yep - thanks for the formatting fix and the quotas note. My use case should fit well within the quotas - appreciate the heads-up, though.

Comment: Just a piece of info (relatively obscured in docs, though) to keep track of (the quotas are generally sufficient for a general use case, though). Btw, another side note (on code style) - please, doný use sentence-cased var names if possible ( conventionally they designate "classes" [inasmuch JS has them] ) - not relevant here, but may become a source of confusion later in the game

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to uncomment your `MailApp` code.*

#### Code changes:

I tested your code and it seems to run without issue for me, including the receipt of the emails, only that the code comments around your `MailApp` call need to be removed (the `/*` and the `*/`).

I would also suggest adding a conditional line before you send the email in the event `.getDataRange()` obtains seemingly empty rows:

```
if (Email == "") {
  continue;
};
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: Email,
  subject: Name + Title + 'Test',
  message: 'This is a test message for the training that can be found at ' + URL});
```

#### References:

- [JavaScript Comments](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
function sendEmailLoop() {
  var exclA=['Summary'];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    if (exclA.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) {      
      var range=sheet.getDataRange();
      var values=range.getDisplayValues(); 
      var lastRow=range.getLastRow();
      var Title=values[0][0];
      var URL=values[0][1];  
      var logContent='';
      for (var i=3; i <values.length; i++) {   
        var Name=values[i][0];
        var Email=values[i][1];
        Logger.log('to: %s\nsubject: %s %s Test\nmessage: %s This is a test message for the training that can be found at %s',Email,Name,Title,URL);
        /*
        MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: Email,
        subject: Name + Title + 'Test',
        message: 'This is a test message for the training that can be found at ' + URL});
        */
      }
    }
  });
}
```